# How do you test that an Iterator/ListIterator works?

Tags: java, testing, linked-list, iterator, listiterator

I have an implemenation of a single linked, linked list. I have written a `ListIterator` for this class. How can I test that my implementation for the `ListIterator` works? So far I have used a `for-each loop` on an instance of my linked list, which works. In what other ways do I need to test it?

Comment: Test that all of the methods work exactly the same as a ListIterator on `ArrayList`, on a variety of input lists (empty, singleton, repeated elements etc).

Comment: Take a look at [Guava-testlib](https://blog.codefx.org/techniques/testing/test-collection-implementations-with-guava/). It contains some test harnesses for Iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you want to test all the edge cases in addition to the "normal" case. Maybe:

- test with an empty list
- test with some nulls in
- test an exception is thrown if hasNext() returns false and you try to fetch another element
- test remove()
- test remove() when removing the last element
- test calling remove() twice throws an exception

etc..

Comment: How would I test that the `previous()` method I have written in the iterator works?

Comment: Much like next()? :) Make a list, move forwards and backwards a bit? Test the edge cases in the opposite direction..